# Asserting the response data getting failed

Tags: jmeter

I'm executing an URL in JMeter for which the response data will be like

```
{"RESPONSECODE":1,"ERRORCODE":0,"REGID":123}.
```

I need to assert this data for Response code & Error code, so I added 
`Response Assertion` to the Thread Group and constructed a regular expression like

```
/^\w+(?:RESPONSECODE)(?:1)?(?:ERRORCODE)(?:0)?(?:REGID)[0-9]/`.
```

Regid will be a random integer. I should not get any other integer for Errorcode but `0`. Have also selected Response Message & Contains radio buttons in Response Assertion.

But the assertion failed, even when the response code and error code are as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice you can use [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) with checking Path

```
$.ERRORCODE
```

And check `Additionally assert value` and `Match as Regular expression` with Expected value:

```
[0]{1}
```

This will check that only `0` is return

[image]

Comment: Yes, it throws exact output. But for further requests the text ERRORCODE is displayed as ERRCODE and then the test is getting failed. Is there anyway to handle this with JSON Assertion?

Comment: use different Path `$.ERRCODE`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but then all requests are getting asserted for both 'ERRORCODE' & 'ERRCODE' and hence all tests getting failed. Here I need to check the ERRORCODE only for the 1st request and then ERRCODE for further requests.

Comment: You need to put each Assertion **under** relevant request so it will be executed for it only (or under controller for several requests)

Answer (score 1):

1. Change "Field to test" to `Text Response`
2. Change your Regular Expression to look like:

   ```
   {"RESPONSECODE":(\d+),"ERRORCODE":0,"REGID":(\d+)}
   ```

---

Also be aware that there is a [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) which is way more handy to assert [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) response data type

Comment: It works precisely. Thanks but I am sequentially running 5 requests by storing values from each response and passing the values sequentially to further requests. From 2nd request onwards the text REGID will get changed as 'ID'  and all further assertions getting failed. Should I add that as another condition?